# Inverted File vs Signature File

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine, information-retrieval

With respect to Information Retrieval,

I fairly understood the concepts of inverted indices/files. Got to know that signature file was compared much inverted file. But I dont understand concept behind the Signature file concept ?

Could anybody explain the difference or point out where i can read about it ?

Comment: Another paper with descriptions of several different types of each index is this one [Inverted Files Versus Signature Files for Text Indexing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.120.576&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good explaination on page 6 of [this paper](http://www.users.muohio.edu/canf/papers/ipm04b.pdf). Currently, I am not convinced of an advantage of signature files over an inverted index.